# $p$'th roots in an extension of prime degree $p$.

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, radicals

Let $F$ be a field of characteristic $0$, and let $p$ be a prime number. Choose an element $r\in F$ and suppose that $r$ has no $p$'th root in $F$. Let $F':=F(\sqrt[p]{r})$, this is an extension of $F$ of degree $p$. Set $\alpha:=\sqrt[p]{r}$ for convenience.

My question is this: Given an element $\beta\in F'$ such that $\beta^p\in F$, is it true that $\beta=c\cdot\alpha^k$ for some $c\in F$, $k\in\mathbb{N}$? In other words, it it true that the only elements of $F$ that have $p$'th roots in $F(\sqrt[p]{r})$ are the "obvious" elements $c^p\cdot r^k$?

This is true if $p=2$ or $3$, which I discerned through direct computation, which would become impractical for higher values of $p$. If anyone has any ideas for how to approach the general case, it would be very helpful.

Comment: What is $\alpha$?

Comment: Sorry, $\alpha$ should be $\sqrt[p]{r}$. I'll change that.

Comment: Look at $F = \Bbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$ and $r \in F^*, \not \in (F^*)^p$ then $Gal(F(r^{1/p})/F) = \{ \sigma^0,\ldots,\sigma^{p-1}\}$ where $\sigma(r^{1/p}) = \zeta_p r^{1/p}$. If $b \in F(r^{1/p}),b^p \in F^*$ then $b$ is a root of $x^p-b^p$ so for some $m$, $ \sigma(b) = \zeta_p^m b$ and $\sigma(r^{-m/p} b ) = r^{-m/p} b$, thus $r^{-m/p} b \in F^*$ so that $b^p \in (F^*)^p r^m$.

Comment: That's excellent, and this argument actually works for any field containing a $p$'th root of unity, which I think I can assume. Thanks!